# I have a code like this but i got an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trying to run this program but i got an error

```
import sys
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import callbacks
import time

start = time.time()

DEV = False
argvs = sys.argv
argc = len(argvs)

if argc > 1 and (argvs[1] == "--development" or argvs[1] == "-d"):
  DEV = True

if DEV:
  epochs = 2
else:
  epochs = 20

train_data_path = 'data/train'
validation_data_path = 'data/test'

"""
Parameters
"""
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
batch_size = 32
samples_per_epoch = 1000
validation_steps = 300
nb_filters1 = 32
nb_filters2 = 64
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
pool_size = 2
classes_num = 3
lr = 0.0004

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters1, conv1_size, conv1_size, border_mode ="same", input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters2, conv2_size, conv2_size, border_mode ="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

"""
Tensorboard log
"""
log_dir = './tf-log/'
tb_cb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0)
cbks = [tb_cb]
print("testing purpose")
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=samples_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=cbks,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

target_dir = './models/'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
model.save('./models/model.h5')
model.save_weights('./models/weights.h5')

#Calculate execution time
end = time.time()
dur = end-start

if dur<60:
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"seconds")
elif dur>60 and dur<3600:
    dur=dur/60
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"minutes")
else:
    dur=dur/(60*60)
    print("Execution Time:",dur,"hours")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Training.py", line 95, in <module>
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 217, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1211, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Desktop/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Comment: It seems your dataset has only two classes in the train or validation directory means you have only two subfolders in the train or validation directory.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your classes_num = 3 but training data only have 2 class